# In Wii Sports Resort, can I have an overview of all my stamps?

Tags: wii-sports-resort

Is there an overview of all stamps for all games somewhere? So far, my only option is to access (and start playing) every single game in order to see what stamps I am missing, which is quite annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a stamp overview page. However, as a low-tech solution you could note on paper which stamps you have completed, like this:

Air Sports: (x) (x) (x) ( ) ( )

Archery: (x) ( ) ( ) (x) ( )

Comment: There is a list of stamps here if it helps: http://uk.guides.ign.com/guides/14266992/page_3.html - copy-paste or write them all down and tick them off.

Comment: I had seen that PDF but you have to be an IGN Insider to view it.

Comment: I just meant the list on the website (click each game to see the stamps), I didn't see the bit about the PDF.